# PrimeFaces Ajax listener in SelectOneMenu tag is not working with viewParam

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, viewparams

I trying to use a selectOneMenu ajax listener but its not working when my page receives parameters.

In my tests I used the same example shown in PrimeFaces ShowCase page, but my page also receives parameters by viewParam and viewAction.

The first time the selectOneMenu is changed the action listener is triggered, and then it stops working.

My page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{dropdownViewBean.id}" required="true" />
        <f:viewAction action="#{dropdownViewBean.init}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

            <p:panel header="Select a Location" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Country: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{dropdownViewBean.country}" style="width:150px">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{dropdownViewBean.onCountryChange}" update="city" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownViewBean.countries}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{dropdownViewBean.city}" style="width:150px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownViewBean.cities}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:separator />

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" actionListener="#{dropdownViewBean.displayLocation}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "dropdownViewBean")
@ViewScoped
public class DropdownViewBean implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private Map<String, String> countries;
    private Map<String, String> cities;

    private int id;

    public DropdownViewBean() {
    }

    public void init() {

        System.out.println("init id=" + id); // message is correctly shown when page starts

        countries = new HashMap<String, String>();
        countries.put("USA", "USA");
        countries.put("Germany", "Germany");
        countries.put("Brazil", "Brazil");

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("New York", "New York");
        map.put("San Francisco", "San Francisco");
        map.put("Denver", "Denver");
        data.put("USA", map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Berlin", "Berlin");
        map.put("Munich", "Munich");
        map.put("Frankfurt", "Frankfurt");
        data.put("Germany", map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Sao Paolo", "Sao Paolo");
        map.put("Rio de Janerio", "Rio de Janerio");
        map.put("Salvador", "Salvador");
        data.put("Brazil", map);
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void onCountryChange() {

        System.out.println("change"); // message is shown only the first time the combo is changed

        if (country != null && !country.equals("")) {
            cities = data.get(country);
        } else {
            cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    }

    public void displayLocation() {
        FacesMessage msg;
        if (city != null && country != null) {
            msg = new FacesMessage("Selected", city + " of " + country);
        } else {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid", "City is not selected.");
        }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Important:

If I took out the metadata, viewParam and viewAction tags and mark the init() method with @PostConstruct then the sample works perfectly, but I need the page parameter.

I ask your help to solve it.

Comment: Which JSF version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.2.6 on Glassfish 4.0 and Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: @RobinsonRK - I'm not entirely trusting of the new `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` and I've had some weird behaviour with it myself. You could still pull the request parameters off the wire, from within `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Did my answer stop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.

Replace the tag

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{dropdownViewBean.id}" required="true" />
```

With

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{dropdownViewBean.id}"/>
```

Unfortunately I don't have an explanation about this Bug

Comment: Hello, this is an old question but still a common issue. I discovered its because the Ajax does a submit and doesn't send the param. When the page doesn't receive the required param it throws an error. Your answer is correct but I prefer to use the OmniFaces components to validate the param.

Answer (score 1):

I have my distrust of the `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`, I've just been too lazy to file an issue. For one thing, you don't have to use that type of `ViewScoped` *yet*; it was introduced to lead to the eventual deprecation of `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`. As at now, it's still very valid and just as applicable.

The only restriction on that annotation is that it's not applicable to a CDI bean and it's the only viewscope that will allow the `@Inject` annotation. It doesn't appear you're in need of it, so you should be able to safely remove it.

---

You can still pull the GET parameters from within your `@PostConstruct`, old school:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
   FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   Map<String,String> requestParameters =  ctxt.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

   int id = Integer.parseInt(requestParameters.get("id")); 


}
```